# How to pass arguments to constructor when using string containing linkage identifier for a movie clip symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm using AS3 `htmlText` property of `TextField` and I want to embed custom sprite into html. [The documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) says, you can use *linkage identifier for a movie clip symbol in the library* for this. So I wrote:

```
public class ImageWrapper extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source = 'test.png')]
    private var TestImg:Class;

    public function ImageWrapper()
    {
        var bitmap:Bitmap = new TestImg();
        addChild(bitmap);
    }
}
```

And then as `htmlText`:

```
myTextField.htmlText = "Test <img src='" + getQualifiedClassName(ImageWrapper) + "'>";
```

And this works perfectly. But when I try to pass anything via constructor, changing definition to

```
public function ImageWrapper(foo:int)
```

And updating html to:

```
"Test <img src='" + getQualifiedClassName(ImageWrapper) + "(400)'>";
```

I am getting `Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.`

I searched docs, but I didn't find a way to pass arguments for constructor. Am I missing something, or it's simply impossible to do so? I only need to send primitives to my constructor (like `int` or `String`)

Comment: What is the purpose of the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's impossible to pass any additional parameters to html image class, the only way is to have as many classes as many options you have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a workaround:

```
public class ImageWrapper extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source = 'test.png')]
    private var TestImg:Class;
    public static var x:int = 0;
    private var loc_x:int;

    public function ImageWrapper()
    {
        loc_x = x;
        var bitmap:Bitmap = new TestImg();
        addChild(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Then in my code:

```
ImageWrapper.x = 400;
myTextField.htmlText = "Test <img src='" + getQualifiedClassName(ImageWrapper) + "'>";
ImageWrapper.x = 200;
myOtherTextField.htmlText = "Test2 <img src='" + getQualifiedClassName(ImageWrapper) + "'>";
```

The drawback is you can only use as many `ImageWrapper`'s in single htmlText as you have ImageWrapper definitions (so you need to create classes `ImageWrapper1`, `ImageWrapper2`, etc.)

Comment: Yep, sure, if you creates images like that in a queue you can use any static storage for variables :)